# ProxyHTMLURLMap not working in apache2.4

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2.2, apache2.4

I am using apache2.4 on ubuntu 14.04. And I have enabled mod_proxy_html.But my URL are not getting replaced by a new one. Same thing I did in apache2.2 and it was working perfectly. This is my Virtual host file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.example.com
LogLevel error
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com_access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com_error.log

#Proxy and cookies settings
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/example/control/
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.example.com/example/control/
ProxyPassReverse / /example/control/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /example /

    <Proxy balancer://cluster>
        BalancerMember ajp://10.14.78.45:8009 route=node01 keepalive=On loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600
        ProxySet timeout=60 stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
    </Proxy>

RewriteEngine On

#redirect non www domain to www domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

#Website    
RewriteRule ^/;(.*)$ balancer://cluster/example/control/main;$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ balancer://cluster/example/control/main [P,L]

SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyHTMLExtended Off
ProxyHTMLInterp On
ProxyHTMLDoctype XHTML Legacy
LogLevel debug

#Rewrite home page link
ProxyHTMLURLMap ^(.*)/example/control/main;(.*)$ $1/;$2 [R]
ProxyHTMLURLMap ^(.*)/example/control/main$ $1/ [R]
```

I guess ProxyHTMLURLMap is not working here. Please let me know if something is not configured properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of research I got simple solution with little luck.

proxy_html.conf file was missing. I have copied this file from apache2.2 to /etc/apache/mods-available and made link in mods-enabled pointing to this file.

```
vi /etc/apache2/mods-available
```

added these lines:

```
# Here's the declaration for W3C HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0

ProxyHTMLLinks  a       href
ProxyHTMLLinks  area        href
ProxyHTMLLinks  link        href
ProxyHTMLLinks  img     src longdesc usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  object      classid codebase data usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  q       cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  blockquote  cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  ins     cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  del     cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  form        action
ProxyHTMLLinks  input       src usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  head        profile
ProxyHTMLLinks  base        href
ProxyHTMLLinks  script      src for

# To support scripting events (with ProxyHTMLExtended On),
# you'll need to declare them too.

ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
        onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
        onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
        onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange
```

creating link in mods-enabled

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_html.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

After that it worked perfectly

Comment: I spend on this 2 days... You saved my life :D